# php - change text colour based on text within a field

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get my code to change the colour of text.
I want the text to change green if the 'returned' field is 'yes' & red if the field is 'no'

The information is being pulled from a database and im running a while statement to get each row in a table.

I am a beginner to php & html so just been playing around but seem to be getting an error with everything I'm trying. The code I've got is;

```
<?php
require_once 'header.php';
require_once('my_connect.php');


if ($returned == "Yes") {
 "font = Green"
    }
else if {
" font = Red"
}
end if

$my_query="select * from loans order by user";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);
?>

<table border=1 cellpadding=10>
<tr><th>Loan ID<th>Product<th>User<th>Expected Return Date?<th>Returned?                     <th>Edit?

<?php
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
$loanid = $myrow["loanid"];
$product = $myrow["product"];
$user = $myrow["user"];
$date_return=$myrow["date_return"];
$returned=$myrow["returned"];
echo "<tr><td>$loanid<td>$product<td>$user<td>$date_return<td>$returned
<td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Edit This   Loan?')\" href=editloaninfo.php?loanid=$loanid><img src=\"edit.png\">";

endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: /i would recommend passing this to jquery or javascript. So basically php passes a variable to javascript and javascript changes the color. PHP is more for server side after all.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code into that:

```
<?php
require_once 'header.php';
require_once('my_connect.php');


$my_query="select * from loans order by user";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);
?>

<table border=1 cellpadding=10>
<thead>
<tr><th>Loan ID</th<th>Product</th><th>User</th><th>Expected Return Date?</th><th>Returned?</th> <th>Edit? </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$loanid = $myrow["loanid"];
$product = $myrow["product"];
$user = $myrow["user"];
$date_return=$myrow["date_return"];
$returned=$myrow["returned"];
echo "
<tr>
<td>$loanid </td>
<td>$product </td>
<td>$user </td>
<td>$date_return </td>
<td style='color: " . ($returned == "Yes") ? "green" : "red" . ";'> $returned </td>
<td><a onClick =\"confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Edit This   Loan?')\" href=editloaninfo.php?loanid=$loanid><img src=\"edit.png\"> </td>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this didn't seem to work for me, just has greengreengreengreen displayed across the screen

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are trying to change your font color, so here's an example:

```
if($returned == 'Yes'){
     $style = 'green'; //or hex value
 }else{
     $style = 'red';
 }

 <td style="color:<?=$style;?>"></td>
```

Comment: I have a table with each row displayed as 
echo "<tr><td>$loanid<td>$product<td>$user<td>$date_return<td>$returned 

If the value in $returned = Yes i want the whole row to change font to green